# How to upload/index a GeoJson file in Elasticsearch using NEST(C#)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have GeoJson File with me which i want to index on Elastic Search through NEST
But Due to lack of expertise I am having trouble in indexing the document
I have created a class which represent the Mapping on ElasticSearch:

```
public class GeoDocument
    {
        [Nest.Keyword(Name = "DocId")]
        public string DocId { get; set; }

        [Nest.GeoShape(Name = "GeoField")]
        public object GeoField { get; set; }
    }
```

But when i use this Mapping to index a Document

```
var polygon = "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[5.856956,51.002753],[5.856928,51.002771],[5.856687,51.002853],[5.856956,51.002753]]]}";

var geoDocument = new GeoJson
{
   DocId = "1",
   GeoField = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(polygon)
};
var IndexResponse = client.IndexDocument(geoDocument);
```

I get a  Result Something like This

```
"_source": {
                    "DocId": "1",
                    "GeoField": [
                        [
                            []
                        ],
                        [
                            [
                                [
                                    [
                                        [],
                                        []
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        [],
                                        []
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        [],
                                        []
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        [],
                                        []
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Comment: This blog might help: https://forloop.co.uk/blog/geospatial-search-with-elasticsearch-and-nest#sthash.hqfcsP9L.dpbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make that JObject saved correctly, you have to tell the ElasticClient to use NewtonSoft .Net serializer.

1. Install [NEST.JsonNetSerializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) package
2. Reference the JsonNetSerializer in your ConnectionSettings
3. If you get 400 after changing the settings, you might need to create a new Index.

**Sample code**

```
using Nest;
using Elasticsearch.Net;
using Nest.JsonNetSerializer;
```

```
    SingleNodeConnectionPool node = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(
        node,
        JsonNetSerializer.Default
    );
    settings.DefaultMappingFor<GeoDocument>(m => m.IndexName("project2"));
    ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    // This is Supposed to be GeoDocument as per your question.
    GeoDocument geoDocument = new GeoDocument 
    {
        DocId = "1",
        GeoField = JObject.Parse(polygon)
        // GeoField = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(polygon) // <-- Works too.
    };

    IndexResponse IndexResponse = client.IndexDocument(geoDocument);
```

**Response**

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "project2",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "COQRXW8BNG2RJmIOyoO0",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "DocId": "1",
                    "GeoField": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
                                [
                                    5.856956,
                                    51.002753
                                ],
                                [
                                    5.856928,
                                    51.002771
                                ],
                                [
                                    5.856687,
                                    51.002853
                                ],
                                [
                                    5.856956,
                                    51.002753
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Jawad, can you please explain this line? `    settings.DefaultMappingFor<GeoDocument>(m => m.IndexName("project2"));` 
How the mappings are stored in settings file? 
Thank you!

Comment: @FlorinVirdol the settings are not from file. It's a property of ConnectionSettings which is part of ElasticSearch

Comment: Oh, ok, i understand now. 
Thank you, @Jawad!

Comment: Hi, again, @Jawad! 
I managed to use your example for ingesting, but `GeoField` property in ElasticSearch is not of type `GeoShape`, but instead, it's an object with two properties (`type` and `coordinates`). How can i add the `GeoField` as `GeoShape`? Thank you!

Comment: How to ingest `GeoField` as `GeoShape`? 
I tried: 1. Your example `JsonNetSerializer.Default` - `GeoField` ingested property in ElasticSearch is not of type `GeoShape`, but instead, it's an object with two properties (`type` and `coordinates`)
2. Added some CustomSerializer in which added NTS `GeometryConverter`), tried to ingest `IFeature.Geometry` but getting error: `Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'coordinateValue' with type 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate'. Path 'GeoField.coordinate'` Thanks!

Comment: @FlorinVirdol I would suggest posting a new question with the issue you see... but seems like you have a self reference loop where you are calling the property within one.

Comment: When / if you have some time to have a look, i asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689842/how-to-index-ingest-geo-data-geometry-geometrycollection-as-geoshape-in-ela Thanks!